# How to update only the source list of a primefaces picklist?

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton, picklist

After submitting with commandButton, I'd like to update a primafaces picklist component... but **only the source part** not the target part. Is it possible to obtain the id of the source list of the picklist in order to update it?

Comment: No you can't.. but why would you do it ?

Comment: @HatemAlimam Because I have a dialog with a picklist (picklist2) (which is filled by the same data) and I want to remove the chosen items from the source of picklist1 when the user choose an item from picklist2  (but I don't want it to display the chosen items in the target of picklist1)

Comment: Even if you have to use the same list for sources... I'm afraid you'll have to duplicate it in the bean to get it for picklist1 and picklist2.

Comment: Finally what have I done is to reload the picklist1 with data at the end of the execution of the commandButton method. it worked well. Thanks to you @rion18 and HatemAlimam.

Comment: What if the user closes the dialog and wants to edit his choices on picklist1?

Comment: @rion18 picklist1 belong to a form to create a new item.. whereas picklist2 (which is in the dialog) belong to a form to edit existing items.. it's 2 different jobs.. So if a user closes the dialog (of editing) and decide to create a new item it causes no problem.

Comment: Ohhhh then I didn't understand the question XD